# TKinter grid and inherited object

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using this code from [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/350266/creating-table-in-python)

I am trying to insert a simple table into a Frame in TKinter. I have adapted the code, but I cant seem to make the new object respect the grid sizing.

The table should be full width and the button should show, but the table is only taking up half the window and its height seems fixed because if I change the main frame geometry height the button shows.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or suggest a better alternative so I don't have to spend the start of next year banging my heads against a wall :)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class frmListMembers(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #self.grid()

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("List Members")
        self.master.geometry("500x240+0+0")        
        self.master.resizable(False, False)        
        self.focus_set()

        container = Frame(master)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10,pady=10)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tblMembers = MemberListBox(container) #.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.OkButton = Button(master, text="DONE", command=self.oKButtonClick).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5), padx=10, sticky="E")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)



    def oKButtonClick(self):

        self.master.destroy()


class MemberListBox(object):
    """use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.container = container
        self.tree = None
        self._setup_widgets()
        self._build_tree()


    def _setup_widgets(self):

        #container = Frame()
        #container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # create a treeview with vertical scrollbar
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=car_header, show="headings")
        vsb = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, xscrollcommand=None)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NSEW', in_=self.container)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='NS', in_=self.container)

        #self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def _build_tree(self):
        for col in car_header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title(),
            command=lambda c=col: sortby(self.tree, c, 0))
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in car_list:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(car_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(car_header[ix], width=col_w)


# the test data ...
car_header = ['car', 'repair', 'price', 'Mileage']
car_list = [
('Hyundai', 'brakes', 10999, 20101) ,
('Honda', 'light', 10999, 20101) ,
]
root = Tk()
frmListMembers(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation so we can test your code.

Comment: Please provide a [a _Minimal_, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or you should start saving for a [head protector](https://www.brownhealthcare.com/images/HeadSaver%20head%20protector%20.jpg).

Comment: @Nae - Its as minimal and complete as I can get. What's wrong with it, other than the issue Novel referred to?

Comment: @Novel - I think I fixed the indents. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @Nae - thanks for letting me know my mistake. I copied the code back from SO into my IDE and it works fines now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I tried to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of OP's code to the best of my efforts while still preserving your code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class frmListMembers(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("500x240+0+0")        
        self.master.resizable(False, False)

        container = Frame(master)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10,pady=10, sticky='ew')
        self.tblMembers = MemberListBox(container) #.grid(row=0,column=0)

        Button(master, text="DONE").grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5), padx=10, sticky="E")


class MemberListBox(object):
    """use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.container = container
        self.tree = None
        self._setup_widgets()
        self._build_tree()


    def _setup_widgets(self):

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=car_header, show="headings")
        vsb = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, xscrollcommand=None)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NSEW', in_=self.container)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='NS', in_=self.container)

    def _build_tree(self):
        for col in car_header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title())
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in car_list:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(car_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(car_header[ix], width=col_w)


# the test data ...
car_header = ['car', 'repair', 'price', 'Mileage']
car_list = [
('Hyundai', 'brakes', 10999, 20101) ,
('Honda', 'light', 10999, 20101) ,
]
root = Tk()
frmListMembers(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Using above code I've replaced from:

```
container.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10,pady=10, sticky='ew')
```

line to the line below:

```
class MemberListBox(object):
```

with:

```
container.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10,pady=10, sticky='nsew')   # expand
self.tblMembers = MemberListBox(container)
container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)        # allow tree to resize height
container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)     # allow tree to resize width
#container.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)    # don't allow scrollbar to rsz
self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # allow container to resize
self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # both its width and height

self.OkButton = Button(container, text="DONE")  # put button in container
self.OkButton.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5), padx=10, sticky="E")
```

that resulted in:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class frmListMembers(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("500x240+0+0")        
        self.master.resizable(False, False)

        container = Frame(master)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10,pady=10, sticky='nsew')   # expand
        self.tblMembers = MemberListBox(container)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)        # allow tree to resize height
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)     # allow tree to resize width
        #container.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)    # don't allow scrollbar to rsz
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # allow container to resize
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # both its width and height

        self.OkButton = Button(container, text="DONE")  # put button in container
        self.OkButton.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5), padx=10, sticky="E")


class MemberListBox(object):
    """use a ttk.TreeView as a multicolumn ListBox"""
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.container = container
        self.tree = None
        self._setup_widgets()
        self._build_tree()


    def _setup_widgets(self):

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=car_header, show="headings")
        vsb = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set, xscrollcommand=None)
        self.tree.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NSEW', in_=self.container)
        vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='NS', in_=self.container)

    def _build_tree(self):
        for col in car_header:
            self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title())
            # adjust the column's width to the header string
            self.tree.column(col,width=tkFont.Font().measure(col.title()))

        for item in car_list:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)
            # adjust column's width if necessary to fit each value
            for ix, val in enumerate(item):
                col_w = tkFont.Font().measure(val)
                if self.tree.column(car_header[ix],width=None)<col_w:
                    self.tree.column(car_header[ix], width=col_w)


# the test data ...
car_header = ['car', 'repair', 'price', 'Mileage']
car_list = [
('Hyundai', 'brakes', 10999, 20101) ,
('Honda', 'light', 10999, 20101) ,
]
root = Tk()
frmListMembers(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Note: There's not a single part of this 'answer' wouldn'tve been much easier if the OP provided a more minimal example.